# Alias added to /etc/bash.bashrc does not work for Debian 11

Tags: bash, debian, alias

I have a Debian docker. In one line I define an alias in `Dockerfile`:

```
RUN echo alias Kill="ps -ef | grep 'dotnet' | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | xargs -r kill -9" >> /etc/bash.bashrc
```

And when I build this docker image and run it, I can verify the line is appended to the `/etc/bash.bashrc` file.

However, when I type `Kill` I get:

> bash: Kill: command not found

What do I do wrong here?

Comment: What shell is your docker image running? Is it `bash` or is it maybe `sh`? Does it work as expected if you add it to `/etc/profile` instead?

Comment: That will output `alias Kill=ps -ef | grep ....` to the file, and that will fail since the lack of quoting means `-ef` will be seen as options to `alias`, which doesn't understand them

Comment: @terdon, it's `bash`. I have not tested the `/etc/profile`. But doesn't it load `/etc/bash.bashrc`?

Comment: @muru, What should I do to preserve double quotes?